# how to replace electron js default icon with custom icon from window title

Tags: electron

I am trying to replace electron js default icon with custom icon from window title. As I am new to electron js, need help regarding this.

please refer below image

[View icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeHL5.png)

Answer (score 0):

In main.js in your function where you create the window add

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  icon: './pathTo/myIcon.ico' // <-- this line
  });
```

to your create Window function. Of course you have to provide a valid windows icon on this path.